# Function in Matlab not working correctly

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write the following function which computes the sum of the series 1 + x^1 + ... + x^n. I have

```
function[result] = sumGP(x,n)
if x == 1
    result = n+1;
else
    result = (x^(n+1) - 1)/(x-1);
end

sumGP(1,4)
```

If I want to call this function using 'sumGP(1,4)', the output should be '5'. But Matlab is saying 'undefined function of variable 'x'.

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: by using the command 'sumGP(1,4)' in the last line. Is that wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the function from _within_ the function?

Comment: Ok, I ended my function now, and called it from outside. But I'm still getting the same error. It seems the 'run' button is on an infinite loop.

Comment: @Kamil **NEVER** try to "run" functions by pressing the 'run' button. Always **Call** them from the command line instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate m-file for this:

```
function[result] = sumGP(x,n)
if x == 1
    result = n+1;
else
    result = (x^(n+1) - 1)/(x-1);
end
```

and a separate m-file for this: `sumGP(1,4)`

or use `sumGP(1,4)` in command window.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem! Very good tip, thank you. It works now.